Indexing on Value Part of HashMap in mongo
I have a hashmap in my mongo document which is null or empty 70% of times.
Map : Map<String, String> selectedSmsVendorMap
This map stores the final sms vendor name (value) chosen for a mobile number (key) in the map.
 "selectedSmsVendorMap": {"1234567890": "sms-vendor-1"}
I need to create an index on the name of vendors which are present as value. This is to be able to fetch the records and count for any particular vendor name in a time duration.
This map may have multiple entries.
The number of records in the collection are in hundreds of  millions as the user base (mobile number) is huge. However the number of sms vendors are less that 5.
How should I create index here? And how to query the data here as well? (say, fetcg documents which have sms-vendor-1 as value)

Have you tried a wildcard index?

Better to use the Attribute Pattern. For example: "selectedSmsVendorMap": {"number": "1234567890", "vendor": "sms-vendor-1"}. Then you can create your index on selectedSmsVendorMap.vendor.

@Joe how to include wildcard index here as this is present in the value part of the map? Could you guide me here?

@aneroid the issue is failing to get the old data that is present in this structure already.
